# Joomla - Custom fields in Backend - Template override

Tags: administrator, template-override, custom-field

I have a Joomla-site with a lot of extra-fields in custom fields area. When I edit my articles the long list of fields is quite confusing. So I thought I could be a good idea to show the custom fields in backend in two columns like it is in the "images and links"-tab. Don't know what I mean. Look here for an example: [image: Custom-fields backend]

Of course I could write my own override for the template, but where the hell is the view of fields-tab in backend built up? The individual fields are in a container named "control-group" but I don't find the pivotal file in /administrator/components/com_fields

Could anybody please help me out of this dilemma? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Custom Fields are added to forms by `System - Fields` plugin.

Before doing template override I suggest checking out Field Groups feature. Each field group has its own fieldset which results in a separate tab in form view:
[image]

If this solution doesn't suit you, you can override form view layout:

```
administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php
```

In the override add `fields-0` fieldset to ignored fieldsets array:

```
$this->ignore_fieldsets[] = 'fields-0';
```

And then render the fields manually:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'fields', JText::_('JGLOBAL_FIELDS')); ?>
    <div class="row-fluid form-horizontal-desktop">
        <div class="span6">
            <?php echo $this->form->renderField('field-1', 'com_fields'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <?php echo $this->form->renderField('field-2', 'com_fields'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
```

You can also combine both methods to avoid having to render each field by name and instead use fieldsets (field groups). E.g. create two field groups, assign fields to them. In the override exclude the groups:

```
$this->ignore_fieldsets[] = 'fields-1';
$this->ignore_fieldsets[] = 'fields-2';
```

And then render them:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'fields', JText::_('JGLOBAL_FIELDS')); ?>
    <div class="row-fluid form-horizontal-desktop">
        <div class="span6">
            <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('fields-1'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('fields-2'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
The solution with groups isn't suitable for me, because i this case the large number of fields is only divided into two or more long columns.
The file you mentioned "administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php" is creating the main content and the publishing-tab etc. but not the fieldset.
When I add the line 

  <?php $this->ignore_fieldsets[] = 'fields-0'; ?>
it unfortunately doesn't change anything...
Maybe it is another file???

Comment: That line has to be added after this: `$this->ignore_fieldsets = array('jmetadata', 'item_associations');`. Or you can add `fields-0` in the same line: `$this->ignore_fieldsets = array('jmetadata', 'item_associations', 'fields-0');`. Also, instead of editing the file directly you should override it. See override documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core.

Comment: Yeah of course I'll do an override... At the moment it is just for testing the behaviour. Thank you, now I understand it better...

Comment: btw. in my joomla-installation it isn't possible to choose the fields-group in the fields. When I click on it it shows only "none"
And another thing is... Why isn't it possible to change the type of an field after creating it... But therefore I can handle it via sql...
But thanx again. I think this will help a lot...

Comment: You have to create a field group before you can select it. Changing field type would cause various issues, e.g. some fields would not display correctly because some types stores values as text while others store as JSON object or array.

Comment: Yes, I created 3 groups before...
And I did a test with your very intuitive solution above with the renderFieldset. But the result is the same. The fields are only shown in one long column. The span6-option didn't work. But I think I will fix this with css and a new class...