# How can I override custom fields layout for the Administrator side?

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, custom-field

I'm using Custom Fields in articles intensively.

I need to override the Custom Fields edit layout on the administrator side.
Editing the files created via Administrator Template Overrides do not work.

As an example, any edits to file `administrator/templates/atum/html/plg_fields_sql/sql.php` have no impact on the SQL custom fields layout when I edit an article on Joomla Administrator.

Ideally, I'd like to create my own custom layout as described [here](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/may-2021/explore-the-core-play-with-custom-fields-to-enrich-your-content-or-your-design) but for the editing the fields on the Joomla Administrator side.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you read this? https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24295/joomla-custom-fields-in-backend-template-override